# How to select/use the value from datetime input in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, datetime

I am new in coding. How can I select the value from a datetime input with JQuery? I need to use it for further calculation. 
Thanks

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="d04" type="datetime-local" name="a_date">
<label for="d04">a_date</label>
<br>
<button onclick="console.log($('#d04').val())">Show value</button>
```

Comment: Same as with most other fields, presumably ...?

Comment: @CBroe I tried $(‘#d04’).val(); but it doesn’t work.

Comment: You're using "fancy" quotes there, you need to use either `"` or `'` ...

Comment: @CBroe this was only in the answer, because the stupid ios11 made the quote looking stupid. In the code I use the right one, but. It still doesn’t work.is this the right selection I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#d04').value`

You can check the Mozilla MDN for further information or examples about datetime-local or other stuff

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local